# How to config Windows Apache2.4 to allow specific urls other than "/"

Tags: apache

I have set up and installed Apache2.4 inside of Windows. My goal is to allow specific IP addresses access to a locally hosted web application that processes files. The web application is a simple app that has 4 different pages: dashboard, login, download, and 404 that is written/built with a React Frontend and Django backend. The web app works perfectly fine when I access it locally through localhost, but when I access it from one of the specified IP addresses the only route I can see is the "/" route, which I have default to the login page of the application aka "/login". The weird part is that if I then login, all of the routes are available unless I refresh the page, then Apache responds with "Not Found". How do I config Apache so that if I refresh the page, still serves the route?

After looking around SO and reddit for a few days, here is what I have so far with no luck (all IP addresses have been replaced with generic ones):
**httpd.conf**

```
Define SRVROOT "c:/Apache24"

ServerRoot "${SRVROOT}"

Listen *:8080

LoadModule actions_module modules/mod_actions.so
LoadModule alias_module modules/mod_alias.so
LoadModule allowmethods_module modules/mod_allowmethods.so
LoadModule asis_module modules/mod_asis.so
LoadModule auth_basic_module modules/mod_auth_basic.so
LoadModule authn_core_module modules/mod_authn_core.so
LoadModule authn_file_module modules/mod_authn_file.so
LoadModule authz_core_module modules/mod_authz_core.so
LoadModule authz_groupfile_module modules/mod_authz_groupfile.so
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
LoadModule authz_user_module modules/mod_authz_user.so
LoadModule autoindex_module modules/mod_autoindex.so
LoadModule cgi_module modules/mod_cgi.so
LoadModule dir_module modules/mod_dir.so
LoadModule env_module modules/mod_env.so
LoadModule include_module modules/mod_include.so
LoadModule isapi_module modules/mod_isapi.so
LoadModule log_config_module modules/mod_log_config.so
LoadModule mime_module modules/mod_mime.so
LoadModule negotiation_module modules/mod_negotiation.so
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
LoadModule setenvif_module modules/mod_setenvif.so
LoadModule vhost_alias_module modules/mod_vhost_alias.so

ServerAdmin example@gmail.com
ServerName localhost:8080

<Directory "/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <RequireAny>
        Require ip 1.1.1.1
        Require ip 8.8.8.8
        Require local
    </RequireAny>
</Directory>
<Directory "LOCATION/OF/STORAGE/zips">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <RequireAny>
        Require ip 1.1.1.1
        Require ip 8.8.8.8
        Require local
    </RequireAny>
</Directory>

DocumentRoot "LOCATION/OF/FRONTEND/build"
<Directory "LOCATION/OF/FRONTEND/build">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    <RequireAny>
        Require ip 1.1.1.1
        Require ip 8.8.8.8
        Require local
    </RequireAny>
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.html
</IfModule>

<Files ".ht*">
    Require all denied
</Files>

ErrorLog "logs/error.log"
LogLevel warn

<Directory "${SRVROOT}/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride None
    Options None
    <RequireAny>
        Require ip 1.1.1.1
        Require ip 8.8.8.8
        Require local
    </RequireAny>
</Directory>

<IfModule headers_module>
    RequestHeader unset Proxy early
</IfModule>

<IfModule mime_module>
    TypesConfig conf/mime.types
    AddType application/x-compress .Z
    AddType application/x-gzip .gz .tgz
</IfModule>

EnableMMAP off
EnableSendfile off

LoadFile "PATH/TO/PYTHON3_8"
LoadModule wsgi_module "PATH/TO/mod_wsgi.cp38-win_amd64.pyd"
WSGIPythonHome "PATH/TO/venv"

Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
<IfModule proxy_html_module>
    Include conf/extra/proxy-html.conf
</IfModule>
<IfModule ssl_module>
    SSLRandomSeed startup builtin
    SSLRandomSeed connect builtin
</IfModule>

<IfModule mpm_winnt_module>
    ThreadsPerChild 1920
    MaxRequestsPerChild 0
</IfModule>
```

**httpd-vhosts.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "LOCATION/OF/FRONTEND/build"
    ProxyPreserveHost On
    Alias /static/zips "LOCATION/OF/STORAGE/zips"
    <Location /login>
        AllowOverride None
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 1.1.1.1
            Require ip 8.8.8.8
            Require local
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
    <Location "login">
        AllowOverride None
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 1.1.1.1
            Require ip 8.8.8.8
            Require local
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
    <Location ~ "/login$">
        AllowOverride None
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 1.1.1.1
            Require ip 8.8.8.8
            Require local
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
    <Location ~ "^\/login">
        AllowOverride None
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 1.1.1.1
            Require ip 8.8.8.8
            Require local
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
    <Location "/register">
        AllowOverride None
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 1.1.1.1
            Require ip 8.8.8.8
            Require local
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
    <Location "/404">
        AllowOverride None
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 1.1.1.1
            Require ip 8.8.8.8
            Require local
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
    <Location ~ "\/static\/zips\/*">
        AllowOverride None
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 1.1.1.1
            Require ip 8.8.8.8
            Require local
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
    <Location "/dashboard">
        AllowOverride None
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 1.1.1.1
            Require ip 8.8.8.8
            Require local
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
    <Location ~ "^/dashboard/*">
        AllowOverride None
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 1.1.1.1
            Require ip 8.8.8.8
            Require local
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
    <Location ~ "^\/dashboard\/*">
        AllowOverride None
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 1.1.1.1
            Require ip 8.8.8.8
            Require local
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
    <Location ~ "^\/api\/*">
        AllowOverride None
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 1.1.1.1
            Require ip 8.8.8.8
            Require local
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
    <Location ~ "/api/*">
        AllowOverride None
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 1.1.1.1
            Require ip 8.8.8.8
            Require local
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
    <Location ~ "\/*">
        AllowOverride None
        <RequireAny>
            Require ip 1.1.1.1
            Require ip 8.8.8.8
            Require local
        </RequireAny>
    </Location>
    
    # Servers to proxy the connection, or;
    # List of application servers:
    # Usage:
    # ProxyPass / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # ProxyPassReverse / http://[IP Addr.]:[port]/
    # Example:
    ProxyPass /api http://127.0.0.1:8000/api
    ProxyPassReverse /api http://127.0.0.1:8000/api

    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>
```

As you can probably garner from those files, I'm pretty new to this.
TLDR; How do I config Apache2.4 on Windows so that if I refresh a specific url from a specific ip address, the route gets found? Feel free to ask for more context!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't believe this, but Windows doesn't like the `.htaccess` file that I had placed in my build directory.

I renamed it to `dot.htaccess` and added `AccessFileName dot.htaccess` to the `httpd.conf` file. Inside that `dot.htaccess` file I have `FallbackResource ./index.html`.

Another suggestion that is deleted for some reason now suggested that  I add a rewrite rule which I implemented inside `httpd.conf` as:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ / [L]
```